# if-else vs if performance

Tags: c++, performance, if-statement

Suppose that I want a program that takes a number input from any device, and return -1 if that number is 0, but continue executing the program in all other cases.

In C++, part of that code would be:

```
int main() {
    if(number == 0) return -1;
    /*
        Here the rest of the program
    */
    return 0; // End of program
}
```

or

```
int main() {
    if(number == 0) return -1;
    else {
        /*
            Here the rest of the program
        */
    }
    return 0; // End of program
}
```

---

My question is, which one of these code parts is more efficient?

And yes, I'm talking only about this exact case, when you need to exit the program if it meets a certain condition.

Comment: I would expect them to generate identical code.

Comment: First of all, measure! Secondly, your compiler should be able to see this the same way. LLVM style guide (used on Clang compiler) recommends writing the first one for readability!

Comment: 1. Check with a timer yourself                                                                      2. The difference would be 0.00000000.

Comment: You could have easily benchmarked both versions and found out for yourself... Especially since you only care about this one particular use case.

Comment: The difference (if there is any) will be negligible.

Comment: The difference is especially useless in the context of ending the program. The stuff that kernel has to do to finalize a process is orders of magnitude higher than any difference you can possibly have in your code. Please use whatever is more readable.

Comment: why do you care about effciently returning `-1` from `main`? Wouldnt it make more sense to concentrate on the stuff that is happening **inside** the else block?

Comment: Note that returning -1 from `main` is not portable. To indicate success return 0 or `EXIT_SUCCESS`; to indicate failure return `EXIT_FAILURE`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no performance difference since the generated code is exactly the same:

```
$ echo "int main() { int number; if (number == 0) return -1; return 0; }" | g++ -x c++ -S - -o /dev/stdout | md5sum
9430c430d1f748cc920af36420d160ce  -

$ echo "int main() { int number; if (number == 0) return -1; else {} return 0; }" | g++ -x c++ -S - -o /dev/stdout | md5sum
9430c430d1f748cc920af36420d160ce  -

$ echo "int main() { int number; if (number == 0) return -1; else {} return 0; }" | g++ -x c++ -S - -o /dev/stdout 
    .file   ""
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    cmpl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    jne .L2
    movl    $-1, %eax
    jmp .L3
.L2:
    movl    $0, %eax
.L3:
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any specific difference in terms of efficiency. I think the first code is doing the same thing and there is no need of an `else` since the compiler would already have returned `-1` if the input is `0`.

Answer (score 1):

With compiler optimization turned off if is faster than if-else in some cases.
This is because there is one less possible conditional jump possible at runtime. This is best shown as:

```
if(condition){
    /*code*/
}
else{
    //Jump 1
    /*code*/
}
//Jump 2
```

Vs:

```
if(conditional){
    /*code*/
}
//Jump 1
/*code*/
```

With compiler optimizations on there should be little to no difference in performance as the compiler will do this for you if possible. Branch prediction on hardware will also attempt to use just one of the statements if it can, and the performance hit will only come if the other option is used.

Answer (score -4):

An if-else statement is used for decision making which I assume you already know.

Do not write the entire program, or most of it, in an else block because if anything would go wrong in the if-else statement, that code would never be reached.

The if-else route is primarily better, especially when used with else if. They are both efficient, but use BRACKETS ( Good practice/organization)

When it comes down to it, they are the same statement and have the equal effect, but it depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Like I previously said, do not write the rest of your program in an else block. The risk for your application not running correctly are much higher if so.

```
if(number == 0)
{
    return -1;
}
```

This statement alone would be the best route in your example. No else blocks.

Comment: what "risk" are you talking about?

Comment: The risk of the else block not being reached and the "rest of the program" not being read because of an error of whatever sort. Having the remainder of the program in an else block sets up many risks. Plus, it's bad practice.

Comment: when there is an error it has to be fixed, that has nothing to do with `if` vs `if - else`. Please provide some good arguments instead of throwing phrases. What is bad practice about having part of the program in an else block, if this fits the logic? Sorry, that doesnt make any sense to me.

Comment: If the contents of the `else` would not be reached due to some error (that naturally would occur before the `else` block) the same code would also not be run if left outside the `else` block (all other things being equal). There is no risk there. Either the condition for the `if` is true and thus the rest of the code does not get run either way (due to returning) or an exception is thrown, which, in this example, would still not run the `else` code on account of no exception handling.

Comment: Read his question. He wants to put the remainder of his program in an else block. It doesn't make sense to you because you focus more of your time upon an answer than the question. In his code blocks, you can CLEARLY see his comments, right? Tell me what they say. If the ELSE BLOCK is not reached and the compiler doesn't pick up the error as an invalid value, then it won't be READ.

Comment: We have different perceptions as to this, but arguing upon it isn't a true representation upon the language. It is a multi paradigm language anyways. More than 1 solution, 1 outlook, 1 perception.

Comment: downvoting because answer reads like it was generated by Markov chain.